# New build agent in ADO not able to run builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We recently got a new server to run our builds on so I installed a new agent in the default pool. I disabled the old agent in the default pool on the old server. Now when I run a build it always says "The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests." and nothing is happening. The agent is sitting idle.

Any ideas as to what it could be or where to look for more info?

Comment: Check the job capability requirements and agent capabilities, if they are fully met.

Comment: @Danielson I see there are a lot missing from the agent that isn't working. Is there somewhere that lists what should be there for agents to run specific builds and tasks?

Comment: All build definitions have automatically generated and/or manually defined demands for agents. For Classic Pipelines, when you see job level definition (below pipeline level and above task level), the 3rd category is 'Demands'. There, the demands are either manually entered, or automatically inserted by the task dependency definition. For YAML pipelines I'm not sure, I always define demands manually. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This has just happened at work after upgrading a TFS server to Azure DevOps Server. After upgrading, agents were at version 2.136.1 and all builds yielded the same message as you mention.

The fix was to **update all agents in the pool**. As of this writing the newer version is 2.217.2.

**Caveat**: in our case, the update operation failed silently, leaving freshly downloaded bin_2.217.2 and externals_2.217.2 folders in the agent service folders. Once you see those, you have to stop the agent's Windows service, delete (or move or rename) the original `bin` and `externals` folders, rename the downloaded ones to `bin` and `externals`, and start the agent's Windows service.